# Adding missing row at the end of each id in a groupby

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

In this example more precisely in the **response** column I have modes of transport (bus, car, metro and walk) and destinations (work, home and shopping), the destination is positioned at the end of each id, but some id doesn't have destination and I have to fill by unknown value and increment **num_resp** column value (suppose the **timestamp** and **num_resp** is ordered).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5], 
                   'response': ['car', 'walk', 'home', 'metro', 'walk', 'car', 'walk', 'metro', 'work', 'walk',
                                'bus', 'metro', 'walk', 'shopping'], 
                   'num_resp': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3],
                   'timestamp': ['2018-02-15 07:35:00', '2018-02-15 08:30:00', '2018-02-15 09:00:00',
                                 '2018-02-15 07:00:30', '2018-02-15 07:30:00', '2018-02-15 07:00:00', 
                                 '2018-02-15 07:45:00', '2018-02-15 08:00:00', '2018-02-15 08:35:00',
                                 '2018-02-15 07:30:00', '2018-02-15 07:35:00', '2018-02-15 07:45:00',
                                 '2018-02-15 08:00:00', '2018-02-15 08:30:00']})
```

**Initial dataframe:**

[image]

**What I m looking for:**

[image]

Comment: Why was `unknown` added to 2nd row of ID 2 ? shouldn't the destination be on the 3rd row?

Comment: Sorry it shouldn't be there

Comment: `unknown` shouldn't be there at all or shouldn't be there on row 2 (but should be there on row 3)?

Comment: Fixed, thanks for the remark. the user id=2 used metro and walk but there is no place (destination) for that I put unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
dest= ['work','home','shopping']
def func(x):
    if (~x['response'].tail(1).isin(dest).any()):
        last_row = x.iloc[-1]
        return x.append(last_row)
    return x
df_new= df.groupby('id').apply(func).reset_index(drop=True)
df_new.loc[df_new.duplicated(),'response']='unknown'
df_new['num_resp']=df_new.groupby('id').cumcount()
print(df_new)
```

or

```
dest= ['work','home','shopping']
a = ~df.groupby('id')['response'].tail(1).isin(dest)
df_new=df.append(df.loc[a[a==True].index]).sort_values('id').reset_index(drop=True)
df_new.loc[df_new.duplicated(),'response']='unknown'
df_new['num_resp']=df_new.groupby('id').cumcount()
df_new
```

**output**

```
id  response    num_resp    timestamp
0   1   car     0   2018-02-15 07:35:00
1   1   walk    1   2018-02-15 08:30:00
2   1   home    2   2018-02-15 09:00:00
3   2   metro   0   2018-02-15 07:00:30
4   2   walk    1   2018-02-15 07:30:00
5   2   unknown     2   2018-02-15 07:30:00
6   3   car     0   2018-02-15 07:00:00
7   3   walk    1   2018-02-15 07:45:00
8   3   metro   2   2018-02-15 08:00:00
9   3   work    3   2018-02-15 08:35:00
10  4   walk    0   2018-02-15 07:30:00
11  4   unknown     1   2018-02-15 07:30:00
12  5   bus     0   2018-02-15 07:35:00
13  5   metro   1   2018-02-15 07:45:00
14  5   walk    2   2018-02-15 08:00:00
15  5   shopping    3   2018-02-15 08:30:00
```

Comment: I tried your method on a dataset with (200k) rows and I noticed that the treatment is taking a long time! Have you another alternative please?